# nodejs how to replace ; with ',' to make an sql query

Tags: node.js, replace, quotes, backslash

I have a query that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ('47677;2019;2019;10T-1001-10010AS;A05;International;TieLineKoman-KosovoB;L_KOM-KOSB;2018;NULL;NULL;;NULL;Tieline;NULL;10XAL-KESH-----J;0;3')
```

that is produced by parsing a csv file.

The query is not in a valid form, I have to replace all semicolons with the string ',' (comma inside single quotes). What I want to get is:

```
('47677','2019','2019','10T-1001-10010AS','A05','International','TieLineKoman-KosovoB','L_KOM-KOSB','2018','NULL','NULL','','NULL','Tieline','NULL','10XAL-KESH-----J','0','3')
```

I have tried to do this in many different ways, but I end up with backshlashes added in my string. This is what I get:

```
"INSERT INTO AllocatedEICDetail VALUES ('47677\\',\\'2019\\',\\'2019\\',\\'10T-1001-10010AS\\',\\'A05\\',\\'International\\',\\'TieLineKoman-KosovoB\\',\\'L_KOM-KOSB\\',\\'2018\\',\\'NULL\\',\\'NULL\\',\\'\\',\\'NULL\\',\\'Tieline\\',\\'NULL\\',\\'10XAL-KESH-----J\\',\\'0\\',\\'3')"
```

Any ideas how to do this properly without having the backslashes added?

Thank you!

Comment: xy problem.. fix the csv parsing not the query, then use prepared queries

Answer (score 0):

```
//the string you have
const string = '47677;2019;2019;10T-1001-10010AS;A05;International;TieLineKoman-KosovoB;L_KOM-KOSB;2018;NULL;NULL;;NULL;Tieline;NULL;10XAL-KESH-----J;0;3';
//the string you need:
const targetString = string.replace(/\;/g,',');
```

You specify a small regex between the forward slashes in replace which is a simple ';', give it a 'g' flag for global which will replace all instances, and in the second argument supply what you need it replaced with.

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is const targetString = string.replace(/\;/g," ',' "); , meaning that the single quotes with the comma should replace the semicolon, not just the comma, but again the backslashes are added.

Comment: Try string.replace(/\;/g," ',' "); , write the results out to a simple text file, and see what the result it. It's possible Node is showing backslashes due to the the console output in node showing a raw string. I tried this and got no backslashes in the text file, so you could just try out your query, else we'll have to think or something else.